# Python - Tkinter programming. Changing window title whilst in event loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Hello all at StackOverflow!

Used the site many times, first time i have had to ask a question, so thanks in advance. For a bit of background, i am writing an application similar to Windows  Notepad that has support for encryption. The idea being that data is encrypted before being written to the disk, adding a basic layer of security.

Programs such as the IDLE interpreter change the windows title throughout the course of the event loop. E.G. when you open a new file, the tile of the window changes to the name of the file.

(Was gonna post pics of titlebar, but not enough rep :( )

At first this lead me to believe that i would have to create a new window every time i open a file, however idle manages to append an asterix * to the window title every time ta new file is opened or created/saved.

My class **init**:

```
class pad():

    def __init__(self,window):

        window.title("Cyphertxt(Alpha) - An Encrypted Wordpad")
        self.filepath = ""

        from Resources.icon import ico
        from os import remove

        filename = ico()        
        window.wm_iconbitmap(filename)
        remove(filename)

        yscroll = Scrollbar(window)
        yscroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        menubar = Menu(window)
        window.config(menu=menubar)
        filemenu = Menu(menubar)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New File             Ctrl+N", command=newf)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open                   Ctrl+O", command=openf)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Decrypt               Ctrl+R", command=self.decryptGUI)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save                     Ctrl+S", command=self.encryptGUI)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Overwrite            Ctrl+G", command=overwrite)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Quit!                    Ctrl+Q", command=squit)
        helpmenu = Menu(menubar)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Help', menu=helpmenu)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="About           ", command=about)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Help           F1", command=docs)

        frame = Frame(window).pack()
        self.t1 = Text(window, yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
        yscroll.config(command=self.t1.yview)
        self.t1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

Here i have attempted to reassign the window title, its the last thing to be called before the end of the open file function.

```
    def openf(event=None):

        pad.filepath = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    if pad.filepath == "":
        pass
    else:
        pad.t1.delete(0.0, END)
        pad.t1.insert(END, open(pad.filepath, "rb+").read())
        **pad.window.config(title=" %s Cyphertxt - An Encrypted Wordpad" % (pad.filepath))**



AttributeError: pad instance has no attribute 'window'
```

Then i tried to call the change from within the class by creating a simple method and calling that from the openf function:

```
    def changetitle(self):
        self.window.config(title="%s CypherTXT - An Encrypted Wordpad)

def openf(event=None):

    pad.filepath = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    if pad.filepath == "":
        pass
    else:
        pad.t1.delete(0.0, END)
        pad.t1.insert(END, open(pad.filepath, "rb+").read())
        **pad.changetitle()**
```

This returned:

```
NameError: global name 'window' is not defined
```

I have attempted to look at the way IDLE manages to do it, but i have not been able to work it out. Effbot tend to be good too, but i cant find an answer there.

I hope i have explained my problem well enough, please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting

```
 self.window = window
```

Somewhere in your `__init__` method. Otherwise, the reference to the `window` object won't be accessible anywhere else.

Comment: I can't believe i missed that... Thanks so much :)

Comment: Seems Tkinter doesnt like C like string formatting %s returns an error, but i'm sure i can work round that simple enough :)

Comment: @0x52-0x75-0x63-0x79: tkinter doesn't have a problem with C-like string formatting. If you're getting an error, you're likely doing something wrong.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Okay, i apologise if i misunderstand, but this is what led me to this conclusion. self.window.title("%s CypherTXT - An Encrypted Wordpad") % (self.filepath) did not work. However self.window.title(self.filepath + "CypherTXT - An Encrypted Wordpad") did work. In fact i had a similar problem with spacing on the Tkinter Menu widgets, wherin '\t' would not add a tab, so i had to resort to adding manual spacing. Could you please explain this so i can understand better?

Comment: `self.window.title("%s CypherTXT - An Encrypted Wordpad") % (self.filepath)` should be `self.window.title("%s CypherTXT - An Encrypted Wordpad" % (self.filepath))`. You can't have a parenthesis between the end of the string and the percent sign. (well, you can, but not if it's part of a function call)

Comment: I see :) It makes perfect sense now you explain it. Thanks for breaking it down for me :D Any explanation of  the escape codes in the Menu buttons?

Comment: Came back to this a lot later, it seems like Tkinter will not accept items such as \n \t ect, this as Tkinter evaluates these in Tcl and not python.